# textbox not appearing while selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to select any of the radio button which makes appear the textbox but pratically it's not working :( .So here is html in the jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
input[type=text]{
  display : none
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="text/html" src="../jscript/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../jscript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> // I 'm using your 1st jquery whose usage is void of css
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').css('display','none');
     $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').css('display','block');
});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<div align="left" style="color:#2D7EE7">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="college"></td> 
<td>College  </td>
<td><input type="text" name="clg"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="school"></td>
<td> School </td>
<td><input type="text" name="schl"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the piece of code of jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
       $('input[type=text]').hide();
       $(this).parent().next().show();
    });
</script>
```

and css :

```
<style type="text/css">
input[type=text]{
  display : none
}
</style>
```

But still this is not working :( :(,so any guess where I'm going wrong.Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change a bit into:

```
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
                $('input[type=text]').hide();
                 $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').show();
            });
```

OR

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
                $('input[type=text]').css('display','none');
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').css('display','block');
            });
        });
```

Comment: `$('input[type=radio]')` i think the radio must be in quotes `$('input[type="radio"]')` correct me if iam wrong

Comment: where I have to add this css text in my code?because in jsfiddle it's working,but in my page it's not working .... any guess why ? :(

Comment: I'll change my code to directly set display css. Let me know if it works

Comment: & where is the css that I have to add

Comment: You can use your current css in the question

Comment: sorry to say that I have tried both of your anwers separately,but still it's not working....any way you have done a very good job, I updated my full code,could you take a look of it..if somewhere I'm going wrong you can catch it.

Comment: Its because you need to put it inside document.ready. Updating my code

Comment: Genius brain U have got,Akhil.. thanks 1cs again for your patience  till the end,and solve my issue.Great

Comment: 1more thing,If in that jsp page there are more than 1 table is present(actually where I'm going to implement it there is already anthoer table exsists for fetch the data from DB),my statement is : will it work there (for more than one table)?

Answer (score 0):

First try to include just one JQuery script into the page (remove jquery-1.4.2.min.js)

`$(':radio')` is equivalent to `$('[type=radio]')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':radio').change(function() {
        // Hide all input:text in the table     
        $('input:text', $(this).closest("table")).hide(); 
        $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input:text').show();
    });
});
```